# fail to import skimage package in python and the error message is: AttributeError: module 'dask.array.numpy_compat' has no attribute 'take_along_axis'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I met a confusing problem today...
When i tried to import skimage as usual, but the error message bellow occurred:
[image]
[image]

some basic information about my python environment:
python version : 3.6
scikit image package version: 0.15.0
numpy package version: 1.13.1
p.s. all the packages were installed via anaconda, and there existed no incompatible issue

It would be appreciated if you can offer any help!!
thanks a lot

I want to know how to fix this problem and import skimage successfully

Comment: `take_along_axis` was added to `numpy` with version 1.15.0.  Your `numpy` is too old.